# Create more hearts?

Tags: yoshis-woolly-world

Like the original Yoshi's Island, clearing a level with maximum hearts (stars in the original) is a requirement for 100%. However, the original had a few ways to accrue additional stars - red eggs would drop 2 stars when broken, and the +10 Star and +20 Star item cards would allow you to top up if you reach the end of a level a few stars short.

Woolly World doesn't appear to have these two options, only allowing you to gain hearts through checkpoints or from item clouds. I've hit the end of a level several times with 15/20 hearts, whilst the last thing that spawned any were considerably earlier in the level. Are there any other ways to top up your hearts?